# How secure Rest-API by token

Tags: spring-data-rest

i use spring data rest 2.1 and would like secure my rest api, what is the best way to secure the api by token. I would have an process like the following steps. Is it also possible to change the base url from / to /api , but my controllers like 'home' would also display the jsp side from /home but not from /api/..

1. User go to login site
2. User login and get an token from server
3. User go to dashboard site and js do ajax call and set HTTP-Header Field 'X_AUTH_TOKEN' with token

Comment: Why do you want to use token authentication for ajax calls ? Session authentication is enough in this use case. IMHO, you should use token authentication only if you have another script, or program that send requests to a web server **outside of a browser**. But what you describe looks ok, you just have to identify login procedure, token time to live, and token storage (memory or disk).

Comment: I wrote a single page application ist session authentication in this case secure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure base URI for you API using `RepositoryRestConfiguration`. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public static class RepositoryConfig extends
        RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(
            RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        try {
            config.setBaseUri(new URI("/api"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You could add security using Spring-Security or if you like a simple custom solution use [Spring Interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)